# App crashes when trying to upload to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

When I try to upload to Firebase my app is crashing with the [following error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG36s.png)

I have an 'upload' button that is being used to invoke the camera. Upon clicking it, the image is not uploaded to Firebase.

My code:

```
private Button mUploadBtn;
private ImageView mImageView;

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

private StorageReference mStorage;

Uri photoURI;

private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

private static final int GALLERY_INTENT = 2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    mUploadBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);

    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    mUploadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Uplaoding");
        mProgressDialog.show();

        Uri uri = data.getData();



        StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Photos").child("file");
        filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });




    }
}
```

Comment: it is clearly written in your error log from the image that you have posted. `Uri can't be null.`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not working with the camera intent correctly.  The code you show is expecting that the intent returned by the camera app contains a Uri to the captured image via its getData() method.  That's not the way it works.

I recommend you follow [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) instead to work with the camera.

Answer (score 0):

override this method
and do the following steps

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        StorageReference image_path = storageReference.child("Camera Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        image_path.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```